# Timestamp on question is later than Profile's Seen, must be some time traveller or ninja

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, last-activity

What kind of ninja skills allows for a user to post a question and have the timestamp appear later than when their profile says they were sighted?

[image: timestamp on question later than last seen]

How did this user post a question without being "seen"?  Shouldn't any of the main actions (posting, commenting) update the last seen field in their account?

Comment: No-repro. [The user's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/508145?tab=activity) last-seen is 10:46:05Z and [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183591/new-function-with-variable-parameters) was asked on 10:51:41Z. Both shows "1 hour ago" now.

Comment: Caching? I know the profile data is cached (check your own now, I bet it doesn't say "seen 0s ago").

Comment: @ChrisF: I assumed it would be a caching thing, but it's not client-side caching (forced reload doesn't fix it) so it could be altered at the server to update the "seen" field whenever a user performs an action that is publicly visible.  Also, when I checked my profile it said "2m ago", even though I hadn't performed any public actions since posting the q.  This suggests "seen" is updated on certain page views.

Comment: @Kenny: doesn't that count as a repro?  He was last seen 5mins 36 seconds before asking his question.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: @Andy: I must be living in Australia :p

Comment: You tried again to use the [ninjas] tag, I see.

Comment: @Grace: yeah, *tried* :-)

Comment: If you don't see them, how do you know they are ninjas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posted questions after last seen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261613/posted-questions-after-last-seen)

Comment: Closing as dupe of much newer post, but with a much better answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Last seen does not mean what you think it means.

It means the last interval check that was made; someone could have activity beyond that, up to the next interval check.

Comment: What the heck is an interval check? And if "last seen" doesn't mean last seen, then why does it say "last seen" instead of "last interval check"?

Comment: @rob in other words, last seen does not mean I have not seen you since I last saw you. It just means THAT was the last time I saw you. I might see you again in 2 minutes, too.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - You seem to have some confusion about the meaning of the word "last".

Comment: if we can have realtime question feed why can't user profile detail can be updated in realtime, it is clearly a bug and should have been accepted as bug OR change text to what Rob suggested

Comment: @JigarJoshi this is known as [tag:status-meh].

Comment: @ShadowWizard how is it called nowadays?

Comment: @Wolf still the same

Comment: @ShadowWizard interesting that this is tagged as [[status-by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)], **also the misleading wording in the user profile**, quite sad to read this.