# The last activity displayed in the profile is inconsistent with the user's actual last activity

Tags: bug, profile-page, last-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Ninjas are posting questions without being seen!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/ninjas-are-posting-questions-without-being-seen)

The user 211425 shows in his [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211425/john) that he was seen 9 hours ago:

[image: Profile]

while there is a comment left to [question 6080736](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080736/adding-a-record-to-a-linq-object-concat-taking-values-from-another) that shows that user was seen 8 hours ago.

[image: Comment]

**[Update]**

If I hover mouse over, it shows the following timestamps:

> Last seen: 2011-05-21 09:02:45Z
> Comment at: 2011-05-21 09:13:28Z

Comment: Mouseover those times until you see a tooltip. What timestamps exactly do you see for each?

Comment: @Chichiray - updated the post with this info.