# How can someone have activity more recent than their "seen" time?

Tags: discussion

This [user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/68855/hoytman) was last seen 19 minutes ago, yet he asked [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181694/what-is-the-opposite-of-compulsion) 13 minutes ago.

Comment: Yes, they can. Seen is only updated periodically. The 'thing' that sees only checks every few minutes.

Comment: Bugger, picked the wrong dupe there. This *is* a dupe though. Good thing Oded found [Timestamp on question is later than Profile's Seen, must be some time traveller or ninja](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70232) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The profile page is cached for about 10 minutes.

So, they asked sometime after someone went looking at their profile.

In other words - [this](http://shouldiblamecaching.com) is relevant.

Comment: "1. Advice may be invalid due to caching" - you noticed it I hope?