# Wrong last seen time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, time

A user have asked a question, and it's marked "asked 7 mins ago"

[image]

I have post an answer and then enter the user profile to see if he had connected after posting my answer. But it's indicated "last seen 22 mins ago".
[image]

I think it's not correct because he already ask a question "7 mins ago"

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to be _that_ accurate. If it was off by a couple of hours, then we'd have something to talk about. But for a few minutes, [let's just blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) and forget about it.

Comment: @Yannis is correct, Shog give official answer in the dupe. You were just on the limit of the 15 minutes. (i.e. reloading again after a minute, you would have seen "Last seen: now")

Comment: @Oded actually while [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/timestamp-on-question-is-later-than-profiles-seen-must-be-some-time-traveller) is older, the answer by Jeff is... not giving much details. Shog gave exact answer on the second dupe. :)